# Fire New Item Alert window using VBA in Outlook 2007

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I want read the 10 first lines of the email and then fire a New Alert Window if a certain condition is met.

How do I fire the New Alert Window using VBA? If not possible is there better way to implement what I want?

Comment: no takers for my question?

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternative.

Generate a message box from ItemAdd code for the Inbox (olFolderInbox) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx

Example for a simple condition:

```
If InStr(Left(Item.Body,1000), "search text here") > 0 then
    MsgBox "You've got mail."
End If
```